# Select Max Date based on another column

Tags: sql, max, maxdate

I have a dataset that has different submissionid's and submissiondatetimes associated with invoicenumbers. I am trying to select just the row(s) with the most recent submissiondatetime for each invoicenumber. Sample data is below, the desired outcome is to only return line 2

Sample queries I have tried are as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    S.SubissionID,
    BookingID,
    InvoiceNumber,
    InvoiceDate,
    NumberofServices,
    SubmissionDateTime
FROM
    [dbo].[Submission] S
JOIN 
    [dbo].[SubmissionInvoice] SI ON S.SubmissionID = SI.SubmissionID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(SubmissionDateTime maxdate 
     FROM [dbo].[Submission]) m ON m.maxdate = s.SubmissionDateTime
```

This only returns records with the most recent SubmissionDateTime regardless of invoicenumber or submissionid.

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 
     S.SubissionID,
     BookingID,
     InvoiceNumber,
     InvoiceDate,
     NumberofServices,
     SubmissionDateTime
 FROM 
     [dbo].[Submission] S
 JOIN 
     [dbo].[SubmissionInvoice] SI ON S.SubmissionID = SI.SubmissionID
                                  AND SubmissionDateTime = (SELECT MAX (SubmissionDateTime) 
                                                            FROM [dbo].[Submission] AS B
                                                            WHERE S.SubmissionID = B.SubmissionID)
```

This max date filtering didn't seem to do anything, results look like they are the same as if I didn't include that part of the query at all.

Comment: TOP 1000 but no ORDER BY will give you a more or less random 1000 rows. Does it matter?

Comment: I could add order by SubmissionDateTime but just trying to get it to work properly first.

Comment: what doesn' work also imges of data are not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions like row_number() if your RDBMs supports it. Here is an example

```
SELECT SubissionID
       ,BookingID
       ,InvoiceNumber
       ,InvoiceDate
       ,NumberofServices
       ,SubmissionDateTime
FROM (
SELECT S.SubissionID
    ,BookingID
    ,InvoiceNumber
    ,InvoiceDate
    ,NumberofServices
    ,SubmissionDateTime
    ,row_number() over(partition by InvoiceNumber order by SubmissionDateTime DESC) AS RN
FROM [dbo].[Submission] S
JOIN [dbo].[SubmissionInvoice] SI 
  on S.SubmissionID = SI.SubmissionID) t
WHERE RN = 1
```